# How to construct a build server if unable to build in one step in Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, build, delphi-xe2

There is a known bug in the last few versions of Delphi that causes a memory leak when compiling large projects and I don't think it has a work around, if it does I'd like to know.

But, if this is just a problem that has no solution, how would one go about designing a build server for a situation such as this?
I might need to have the build server restart itself between builds and pick up where it left off, but that seems cumbersome.

Comment: This probably is better suited on SO, it's about an IDE and specific to implementation, not design. Ask a mod (via flag) to migrate instead of reposting.

Comment: @walter perhaps, if I didn't already know about this bug for over a year with no resolution I would have asked it there.

Comment: @PeterTurner - Just because the bug hasn't been resolved doesn't make the question appropriate to P.SE.  This is a tool question and not a tooling or programming question.

Comment: This is a question about designing a build server if you can't do the build in one step because of physical limitations.

Comment: Build servers use MSBUILD.EXE which invokes DCC32.  BDS.Exe is not involved, and so BDS.exe's memory leaks don't matter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a bug which afflicts the IDE, but won't afflict a build server. That's because the build server does not invoke the IDE. A build server uses the command line compiler to perform the compilation.

Even if the command line compiler had a bug like this it likely would not affect the build server. That's because each time the build server starts a build action, it creates a new process to perform the build. And when that single build is complete, that process terminates. So even if the command line compiler had a memory leak bug, it would not matter because once the compilation was complete, the process would terminate and the memory would be re-claimed by the system.